# Given $y = A\cos2x + B\sin2x$; find the value of $A$ and $B$ if $y = 3$ when $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{dy}{dx} = 4$ when $x = 0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

There is an additional part to this question where it asks to show that $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + 4y =0$. I was able to solve that part but I got stuck where I had to find the values of A and B. In the textbook it says that the values are (-3,2) but I am unable to solve for the answer.

Work:
\begin{align}   
\frac{dy}{dx} &= -2A \sin2x + 2B \cos2x \\  
4 &= -2A \sin(0) + 2B \cos(0) \\
4 &= 2B \\ 
B &= 2,
\end{align}

If $y = 3$, when $x= \frac{\pi}{2}$, then $3 = A \cos\pi + B \sin\pi$.

I don’t know how to move foward beyond this, please help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Hem, what is $\sin \pi$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I’m sorry, I don’t understand what you mean by that.

Comment: @Sinoka: can't you answer ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh, well the value’s 0.

Comment: @Sinoka: isn't that helpful ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ah, I see! I can’t believe I couldn’t answer that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y(x)= A \cos 2x+B \sin 2x$. Then $3=y( \pi /2)=-A$.

We have $y'(x)= -2A \sin 2x+2B \cos 2x$, hence $4=y'(0)=2B$.

Comment: Why the downvote ????????????????????????????????

Comment: I’m sorry, I thought I upvoted it! But since I don’t have much reputation it’s not being publicly recorded.